# GCP Local Cloud Build hanging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

All of a sudden I cannot get GCP local cloud builds running.
I've tried updating the to the latest version of the various pieces
Docker Desktop 2.5.01 Engine 19.03.13
Google Cloud SDK 317.0.0
cloud-build-local 0.5.2

And I have done all possible Windows updates for my current build 2004(19041.572)

If I do a dry run, all is successful and there are no issues.
When I do a full run, a busybox container fires up, status changes to EXITED (0), and that where it all just stops.
Terminal output below

> cloud-build-local --config=cloudbuild-hosting-prod.yaml
> --dryrun=false .
>  2020/11/10 15:12:44 Warning: The server docker version installed (19.03.13) is different from the one used in GCB
> (19.03.8)
>  2020/11/10 15:12:44 Warning: The client docker version
> installed (19.03.13) is different from the one used in GCB (19.03.8)

A colleague of mine is having the same issue, yet if I run the same build on my laptop, all works fine, so its not the YAML file (which hasn't changed anyway) or a code issue
Docker Desktop 2.5.0.0 Engine 19.03.13
Google Cloud SDK 301.0.0
cloud-build-local

Any advice on how to troubleshoot what the issue could be.

Comment: If no error are popping in a dry-run, the yaml should be correct indeed. but the logs you shared do not tell a lot of information, since it's just a warning. Could you share the full terminal output of your build?

Comment: That is the full output, it doesn't go any further than that, its almost seems like the busybox container doesn't fire off the next step, but I can't see any logs anywhere to see what's happening

Comment: Well know its even weirder, as all of a sudden without any changes from yesterday, not even a reboot, my builds are running. Going to test a few more today

Comment: So the issue seems to be a slightly different one, the original project I was testing this on exhibits a very strange and long pause (over 70min) as you can see by the timestamps below.   
cloud-build-local --config=cloudbuild-hosting-prod.yaml  --dryrun=false .  
2020/11/12 08:22:32 Warning: The server docker version installed (19.03.13) is different from the one used in GCB (19.03.8)  

Using default tag: latest  
.....  
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/cloud-builders/metadata:latest  
2020/11/12 09:37:32 Started spoofed metadata server

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, this is indeed strange. I would say that, if the issue still persists, you would need someone from google's official support to inspect your project to check what happened in it, since the logs are not being helpful at all,in case you want to reach to them you can by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support).

Comment: Thanks, yes it still happens. Same project on 2 different machines behaves differently, so something has changed in the versions. I'll make contact with them